# Spring Security redirect url and single page hash fragments

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin, single-page-application, vaadin7

Is any way to configure Spring Security in order to correctly understand hash fragments in a single page applications(built with Vaadin 7 framework)?

After successful login I need to redirect my users to a correct page with hash fragments but Spring Security destroys the original path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by a following trick(I use ThymeLeaf as a template engine):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>

        <script th:inline="javascript">
            function getLoginAction(form){
                var hash = unescape(self.document.location.hash.substring(1));
                form.action = [[@{/login}]] + '#' + hash;
                return true;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Please login</h3> 
        <p th:if="${param.error}">
            Bad Credentials:
        </p>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST" onsubmit="getLoginAction(this);">
            User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> <br/><br/>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/><br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="remember-me"/>Remember Me? <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bring the hash part in your login form, and send the hash back after successful login.

---

Bring hash part with login form submission:

```
<form name='login_form' action="/perform_login" method='POST' onsubmit="getHashPart()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="hashPart" value=""/>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var getHashPart = function () {
        login_form.hashPart.value = location.hash;
    }
</script>
```

---

Create a MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String hashPart = request.getParameter("hashPart");
        if (hashPart == null || hashPart.trim().equals("")) {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        } else {
            this.getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/" + hashPart);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Put your handler into SecurityConfig:

```
        http
            ......
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
            .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
```